# 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i get "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference" whenever i click on the button. help please

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        })
    }

    String tt(){
        return (edt.getText()+"");
    }


public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MainActivity ob = new MainActivity();
    private WebView mywebview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.abc);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl(ob.tt());
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MainActivity ob = new MainActivity();` will get you a simple object of this class not the actual which is currently running  so `ob` is useless in this case ,delete `ob` related code and use `Intent` to pass data

In first `MainActivity`

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("data",edt.getText().toString());
                //              ^^^^ pass data
                startActivity(i);
            }
        })
```

In `Main2Activity`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        mywebview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.abc);
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("data"));
                                    // ^^^^^
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }
```

Also read [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)